# PyWebIO button to refresh the page

Tags: python, button, web-applications, refresh

so I am making a small app, which searches the web via keyword in PyWebIO `input()` function and then shows results in `put_table()` and after the results are ready I need to start another search and instead of updating the page with F5 or browser, I want to create a `put_button()` which will update or get me back to `input()`, can anyone help, please?
Im just not sure what should I put in `onlick=` attribute in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from pywebio.session import run_js

put_button("ReUpload_images",onclick=lambda: run_js('window.location.reload()'))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to quote from the [pywebio documentation](https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#last-but-not-least):

> When you encounter a design problem when using PyWebIO, you can ask yourself a question: What would I do if it is in a terminal program?

The solution in terminal program is to put the `input()` and `put_table()` into a `while` loop. So, in pywebio, you can do the same thing:

```py
from pywebio.input import * 
from pywebio.output import * 

while True:
    keyword = input()
    # make some query
    put_table(...)
```

The table will be appended to the page rather than be updated with this code. So do in terminal program. You can call `pywebio.output.clear()` after the `input()` to clear the page or use [scope](https://pywebio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#output-scope) feature.

```py
from pywebio.input import * 
from pywebio.output import * 

while True:
    keyword = input()
    # make some query
    with use_scope('result', clear=True):
        put_table(...)
```

When you use `while True` in server mode, you don't need to worry about the session will be running forever, because when you close the broswer tab, the pywebio will raise exception in your session to exit it.

In script mode, if you want to provide a way to exit the loop, you can:

```py
from pywebio.input import * 
from pywebio.output import * 

while True:
    keyword = input()
    # make some query
    with use_scope('result', clear=True):
        put_table(...)
    if actions("Continue?",["continue", "exit"])=="exit":
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a button at the end and use `run_js('window.location.reload()')` to refresh the page. Check [the demo on pyweb.io](https://helix.pyweb.io/tab_operation/), and [its source code](https://build.pyweb.io/get/helix/tab_operation)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This answers works for me. I just put `run_js('window.location.reload()')` at the end of my callback to refresh the current page.